# pandas groupby includes dates that is not present

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with the  [e-commerce dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/carrie1/ecommerce-data) and I have the following code snippet

```py
data["grossprice"] = data["UnitPrice"]*data["Quantity"]
total_date = data.groupby(["CustomerID","InvoiceDate"])["grossprice"].sum()
```

with the output

```py
CustomerID  InvoiceDate
12747       2010-12-01                                                   NaN
            2010-12-02                                                   NaN
            2010-12-03                                                   NaN
            2010-12-05     [30.599999999999998, 15.299999999999999, 27.04...
            2010-12-06                                                   NaN
```

and it turns out that the `CustomerID` does not have any transcations on the `NaN` dates.

1. It seems like pandas group on all dates for all customers (and not just the observed), correct? According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the input `observed` can be used to group only on observed combinations (if any of the groupers are categorical), and seems to solve my problem. I can call it without having either `CustomerID` or `InvoiceDate` as categorical, and it seems to work fine. Am I just lucky here, or can I use it like this w/o getting unexpected results?

```py
total_basket = data.groupby(["CustomerID","InvoiceDate"],observed=True)["grossprice"].sum()

[57]

total_basket
CustomerID  InvoiceDate
12747.0     2010-12-05      358.56
            2010-12-13      347.71
            2011-01-20      303.04
            2011-03-01      310.78
            2011-05-05      442.96
                            ...   
18283.0     2011-11-30      220.31
            2011-12-06      208.00
18287.0     2011-05-22      765.28
            2011-10-12     1001.32
            2011-10-28       70.68
```

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded your data.csv file and if I run the following code it gives me the correct output.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

path = "C:/Users/Frank/Downloads/data.csv"

data = pd.read_csv(path, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

data["grossprice"] = data["UnitPrice"]*data["Quantity"]
total_date = data.groupby(["CustomerID","InvoiceDate"])["grossprice"].sum()

print(total_date.loc[12747])
```

which gives the following output

```
InvoiceDate
1/20/2011 14:01     303.04
10/4/2011 8:26      675.38
11/17/2011 17:13    312.73
12/13/2010 10:41    347.71
12/5/2010 15:38     358.56
12/7/2011 14:34     438.50
3/1/2011 14:53      310.78
5/25/2011 9:57      328.35
5/5/2011 15:31      442.96
6/28/2011 10:06     376.30
8/22/2011 10:38     301.70
Name: grossprice, dtype: float64
```

Here is instead the whole `total_date`:

```
CustomerID  InvoiceDate     
12346.0     1/18/2011 10:01     77183.60
            1/18/2011 10:17    -77183.60
12347.0     1/26/2011 14:30       475.39
            10/31/2011 12:25     1294.32
            12/7/2010 14:57       711.79
                                  ...   
18283.0     7/14/2011 13:20         2.50
            9/5/2011 12:35        134.90
18287.0     10/12/2011 10:23     1001.32
            10/28/2011 9:29        70.68
            5/22/2011 10:39       765.28
Name: grossprice, Length: 22034, dtype: float64
```

Comment: What is your pandas version ?

Comment: I have 1.0.4. You think is something new in pandas 1?

Comment: Mine is 1.0.3, so should not make a difference. How does `total_date` look (and not `total_date[12747] ` ?

Comment: If I run just that snippet, Im actually getting the "right" results as well. Im doing some datacleaning first, so that might have some effect though

Comment: I added the whole `total_date` with some additional info

Comment: I also looked at the number of `NaN` in `total_date` and there are None. However in the whole DataFrame `data` apparently there are 1454 `NaN` in `Description` and 135080 `NaN`  in `CustomerID`. No other `NaN` in the other columns.